Intelligently Calculating Return on Ad Spend
Am looking for a way to project return on advertising spend (ROAS). Does not need to be a complex model (in fact would much prefer it if it isn't!).
We have all the data coming in through our SQL pipeline (revenue / subs by campaign, source, adset etc, and based on the attribution date have ROAS after 3 days 7 days 21 / 30 days etc).
What I want to be able to surface in our dashboard is some kind of prediction which is smart enough to update the predicted roas for (e.g.) 30 days, but as time goes on this prediction converges on the actual amount. I.e.. your prediction is calculated from the present performance, so the 30 day roas prediction made for customers converting on (e.g.) 1st October would have some value $x_1$ predicted on the 8th October, but you would expect $x_2$ from (again, e.g.) 28th October to be much closer to the final amount.
Anything that can just be calculated in a Python script or something on a daily run would be absolutely perfect. Any help v much appreciated!
